# Triggering a build script on tag CircleCI

Tags: circleci

I'm trying to trigger a build task when a commit is tagged, however, I cannot make it work, ideally, this exec the task and create the build folder on the release folder only not into the branch.

Notice I'm not trying to deploy to any external.

My config looks like this

```
 test:
  override:
  - yarn test
 deployment:
  release:
   tag: /v[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*/
   owner: ORGNAME
  override:
   - yarn run build
```

Any ideas???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/configuration/#tags

> Normally, pushing a tag will not run a build. If there is a deployment configuration with a tag property that matches the name of the tag you created, we will run the build and the deployment section that matches.

After adding the tag to a task in the `deployment` section, the build will run as normal. If you don't want to do anything specific for that tag, you don't add a `command`.

So:

```
 compile:
   override:
     - yarn run build
 test:
   override:
     - yarn test
 deployment:
   release:
     tag: /v[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*/
     owner: ORGNAME
```